# AWGN continous time channel + colored noise

Tags: noise, continuous-signals, signal-detection, detection

I'm working on an exercise but I'm stuck at the question where the noise becomes colored, can someone help me ?

Let $\{\psi_1(t) = \mathbf{1}\{t \in [0,1)], \psi_2 = \mathbf{1}\{t \in [1,2]\}\}$ be an orthonormal basis. We are sending
$$
w_1(t) = \psi_1(t) + \psi_2(t), \quad w_2(t) = \psi_1(t) - \psi_2(t)\\
w_3(t) = -\psi_1(t) + \psi_2(t), \quad w_4(t) = -\psi_1(t) - \psi_2(t)
$$
across an AWGN channel of power spectral density $N_0 / 2 = 1$. The received waveform is then $R(t) = w_i(t) + N(t)$. At the receiver we observe $Y_1 = \langle R, \psi_1 \rangle$ and $Y_2 = \langle R, \psi_2 \rangle$.

*a) Conditioned on i-th message is being sent, what is the distribution of $(Y_1, Y_2)$.*

I have answered the following

$$
Y_1 = \langle R, \psi_1 \rangle = \langle w_i, \psi_1 \rangle + \langle N, \psi_1 \rangle \sim \mathcal{N}(\langle w_i, \psi_1 \rangle, 1) \\
Y_2 = \langle R, \psi_2 \rangle = \langle w_i, \psi_2 \rangle + \langle N, \psi_2 \rangle \sim \mathcal{N}(\langle w_i, \psi_2 \rangle, 1) 
$$

---

*b) What is the MAP decision region and the corresponding error probability
of this transmission scheme?*

For this, I have :

By looking at the waveform, we see that we use $4$-QAM and the MAP rule is just minimum distance decoding since we have an AWGN channel. The error probability is

$$
\mathbb{P}_e = 2Q(1) - Q^2(1)
$$

---

Now, we will assume that the noise process $N(t)$ is Gaussian but not white, and, for all $t$,

$$
\mathbb{E}[N(t)N(t-\tau)] = \begin{cases}
1-|\tau|, & |\tau| < 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

The receiver does not know of this new noise model, hence it still computes $(Y_1, Y_2)$ and
forms its decision based on the decision region that you have developed in b).

*c) What is the error probability of the receiver under this new noise model?
It is sufficient to give express the error probability as an integral with an explicit
integration region.*

And here I'm stuck, I really don't know what to do... any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, it is necessary to understand what exactly is meant by $\langle R, \psi_1 \rangle$ and $\langle R, \psi_2 \rangle$. These are the outputs of *correlators* or *matched filters* and we have that
\begin{array}{rllll}                   
Y_1 &= \displaystyle{\int_0^1} R(t)\cdot 1 \,\mathrm dt &= \displaystyle{\int_0^1} (-1)^{b_0} + N(t)\,\mathrm dt &= (-1)^{b_0} + \displaystyle{\int_0^1} N(t)\,\mathrm dt &= (-1)^{b_0} + Z_1\\
Y_2 &= \displaystyle{\int_1^2} R(t)\cdot 1 \,\mathrm dt &=\displaystyle{\int_1^2} (-1)^{b_1} + N(t)\,\mathrm dt &= (-1)^{b_1} + \displaystyle{\int_1^2 N(t)}\,\mathrm dt &= (-1)^{b_1} + Z_2
\end{array}
where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are zero-mean Gaussian random variables. What are their variances?
\begin{align}\operatorname{var}(Z_i) &= E[Z_i^2] \\
&= E\left[\int_{i-1}^i N(t)\,\mathrm dt\int_{i-1}^i N(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau\right]\\
&= \int_{i-1}^i\int_{i-1}^i E[N(t)N(\tau)]\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm d\tau\\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1 1- |t-\tau|\, \mathrm dt\,\mathrm d\tau.
\end{align}
Now consider the inner integral $\displaystyle{\int_0^1 1- |t-\tau|\, \mathrm dt}$ for some fixed $\tau \in [0,1]$.  At $t=0$, the integrand has value $1-\tau$.  As $t$ increases, the integrand increases linearly till it reaches value $1$ at $t=\tau$. As $t$ increases beyond $\tau$ towards $1$, $t-\tau$ is a positive number and so the integrand decreases linearly to value $\tau$ at $t=1$. From this, it is easy to work out (do the math for yourself, for crying out loud!) that $$\displaystyle{\int_0^1 1- |t-\tau|\, \mathrm dt = \frac 12+ \tau -\tau^2}$$
(quick check: value is $\frac 12$ at $\tau=0$ and at $\tau = 1$). It follows that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(Z_i) &= \int_0^1\int_0^1 1- |t-\tau|\, \mathrm dt\,\mathrm d\tau\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac 12 + \tau -\tau^2 \,\mathrm d\tau\\
&= \left . \frac{\tau}{2} + \frac{\tau^2}{2} - \frac{\tau^3}{3}\right\vert_0^1\\
&= \frac 23.
\end{align}
The symbol error probability for the receiver can be worked out from this result. Since the noise variance is smaller, we get a smaller error probability. Note that the receiver is oblivious to the fact that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are in fact *correlated* random variables.  Taking the correlation into account and making a *joint* decision on the two bits transmitted instead of individual decisions on the bits would reduce the error rate even more, but that is a whole 'nuther question.

Comment: Awesome work thank you :))